# Vote the promotion ads

Tags: discussion

We have a new ad, it looks like this;

[image: ad]

I have posted it on [Movies.SE](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2141/30785), and Yannis has posted it on [sciFi&F.SE](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7946/community-promotion-ads-2016/8102#8102).

To promote this site, I wish you all to vote these  ads up.

Answer (score 2):

Are there any badges or images that I could feature on my blog?

Comment: No. Just say Join and link and should be fine

Comment: I don't guess anyone would complain about you using this ad, or [any of the ones for 2015](http://meta.mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/157/community-promotion-ads).